# Putting different classes of objects within a same row

Tags: html, css

I was wondering if it's possible in html/css to put different classes of objects within a same row. For example squares. One having height and width of 300px, second 150px, and third height and width of 75px.

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title="Boxes"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="folder/css/exercise14.css">
</head>
<body>
<header class="logo">This is my header</header>
<div class="inline box1"></div>
<div class="inline box2"></div>
<div class="inline box3"></div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
before, after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.logo {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 20px 450px;
    font-size: 250%;
}

.inline {
    display: inline-block;
}

.box1 {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    border: 3px solid;
    margin: 20px;
}

.box2 {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    margin: 20px;
}

.box3 {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 75px;
    width: 75px;
}
```

Comment: You need to add more details.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title="Boxes"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="folder/css/exercise14.css">
</head>

<body>
<header class="logo">This is my header</header>
<div class="inline box1"></div>
<div class="inline box2"></div>
<div class="inline box3"></div>
</body>

Comment: /*CSS*/*,
before,
after{
 -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
 box-sizing:border-box;
}
.logo{
 display:inline-block;
 vertical-align:top;
 margin:20px 450px;
 font-size:250%;
}
.inline{
 display:inline-block;
}
.box1{
 display:inline-block;
 vertical-align:top;
 height:300px;
 width:300px;
 border:3px solid;
 margin:20px;
}

.box2{
 display:inline-block;
 vertical-align:top;
 height:150px;
 width:150px;
 margin:20px;
}
.box3{
 display:inline-block;
 vertical-align:top;
 height:75px;
 width:75px;
}

Comment: add code from comments

Answer (score 0):

Yes, see how it works [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/E8YVxpgdf9lu6nczP6ih?p=preview).

Please note that I added the following rule to `box2` and `box3` so you can see those squares

```
border: 3px solid;
```